# synchronizing two data vectors

Tags: matlab

I have two data vectors, each with a different sampling rate, inside each vector, some of the samples are missed so the sampling frequency isn't fixed. I want to map them together so that I can compare the two graphs at the right times. I know that interpolation (interp1 in Matlab) can be used to fix the irregularity in the sampling frequency in the individual vectors, but how can I map the two vectors to start and end at the same time. 
I have the time vector for each vector, can you guide me on whats the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: So you mean plotting the 2 data on 1 graph?

Comment: yes, I need to take the error between them, I know we can plot them in the same graph even if the number of samples is different, but I need it for comparison as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert two signals to the same time vector, define a new time vector, and call interp1 for each of the input signals.  Below is an example for 2 signals with different sampling intervals (t1 and t2). The first signal (y1) is a sine wave with a magnitude of 1, and the second (y2) is a sine wave with a magnitude of 2.

```
% define first signal with dropouts 
t1 = [0:.02:0.5, 0.7:.02:1]; 
y1 = sin(2*pi*t1);
figure; plot(t1, y1, '.')

% define second signal with dropouts 
t2 = [0:.01:0.2, 0.3:.01:1];
y2 = 2*sin(2*pi*t2);
figure; plot(t2, y2, '.')

% convert both signals to new time 
t_new = 0:0.01:1;
y1_new = interp1(t1, y1, t_new);
y2_new = interp1(t2, y2, t_new);

figure; plot(t_new, [y1_new; y2_new], '.')
```

If the start and end time varies, the code below can compute it.

```
t_new = min([t1(1) t2(1)]):0.01:max([t1(end) t2(end)]);
```

There are several ways to interpolate the values between time intervals (nearest, previous, linear, etc.).  Type the command below for more info.

```
help interp1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! that was very helpful! I can now compare them easily, I've changed the step size in t_new to preserve as much signal as I can